# Typescript: is there a way to restrict something to just a javascript 'object' type?

Tags: typescript

I thought using the type `Object` would do it, but that still allows anything. I want something like this:

```
function foo(arg: /* what goes here? */) { }

foo({})                        // should compile
foo({ something: 'anything'})  // should compile
foo(new Object())              // should compile

foo(7)                         // should not compile
foo('hello')                   // should not compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set `Javascript Object` type constraint in the compile time in TypeScript 1.4. But you can still check the type in the run-time.

```
function foo(arg: Object) {
    if (typeof arg !== "object") { throw new Error("Error"); }

    console.log(arg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually writing a definition file for javascript that does something like that so, a shame it can't be done.